# React-Camera: undefined is not an object(evaluatiing 'CameraManager.Aspect.fill)

Tags: android, react-native, camera, react-native-camera

I got one wired error in **react-native-camera**. Error is `undefined is not an object(evaluatiing 'CameraManager.Aspect.fill)`

It will come when we open application on the second time. For the first time, it works fine.

I tried below steps:
1) Unlink 
2) Uninstalled
3) Installed again.

But it will have the same issue. Can anyone help me to sort out the issue?
Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using react-native-camera along with react-native-navigation. I had added the camera first, then the navigation. The liking step from navigation broke my camera.

After a long debugging, I noticed a problem on `MainApplication.java`. After I extended NavigationApplication, you had to add a new `getPackages` method. I had forgotten to add the content from the old `getPackages`, which included new `RNCameraPackage()`

So, make sure to do the linking process manually.